# Blender file is slow, cannot properly animate or texture because of loading speed

Tags: cycles-render-engine, performance

Blender file is extremely slow, I have to make a complex scene and cannot properly animate or texture because of the low loading speed.
I'm somewhat new to blender, but i have to make a 3D animation of a 3D world where a van drives through a world where all kinda things happen.

But the problem is, the scene/ file is extremely slow, and i don't really know why it is so slow.

I have a 32 GB RAM pc, with a graphic card that has to do the job.

[image: Here you can see the list of collections][image: OVerview of the scene settings][image: Here is an overview of the scene]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Obviously only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe in detail what the issue is, supported by [accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, edit your question and add more information

Comment: Try to put some objects in collections, then disable that collections. Hidden objects will not use CPU time, so that you should work efficient.