# How to animate faster

Tags: animation, bones, collections

I made Satan and added bones etc. Now I would like Satan do dance the Macarena.
I only need to see the bones, but with everting turned off it is still to slow to properly see the bones move. How can I animate the bones without the file being so slow?

I only need to see the mesh for some frames, not during animation. So turning the mesh on and off manually is no problem.

Here someone said disabling collections works, but it does not in my file.
[Blender file is slow, cannot properly animate or texture because of loading speed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266732/blender-file-is-slow-cannot-properly-animate-or-texture-because-of-loading-spee)
[image]

With Frame dropping I see barely any frames, with show every frame it goes to slow and I can't properly see the bones move.

blend-exchange.com doesn't seem to work, but the file is also here https://cults3d.com/en/3d-model/art/satan-south-park You can see I could not really make him move nice, just made 5 positions and rendered it.
[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please use another platform to share your file? You say that Blender is too slow, this is what happens if you try to animate a too high-poly mesh, is it the case? Try to stay as low-poly as possible, use a Subdivision Surface modifier with a level of 1 or 2 in order to smooth the shape

Comment: i am not sure whether Satan wants to dance Macarena.... :D

Comment: well...the model has > 2.7 mio vertices and > 5 mio triangles...so i would say: no wonder it is that slow. I would either use another model or try to decimate the vertices/polygons by decimate modifier

Comment: in the outliner, search for subdivision -> delete or deactivate all -> then the animation is quick. I don't know who just added these subdivision modifiers without thinking, but at least a lot are way to high